# How to connect to local SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

As of now I've been given a piece of software that reads XML files and presents these graphically, to give the user some overview to the events these files describe.

The crux as of now is that one of the engineers using the software has requested that all the data you load into the program should be possible to save to a database.

My pickle is as follows:

```
public void addToDBO(List<List<EventElement>> insertList)
{
    SqlConnection s1 = new SqlConnection();
    s1.ConnectionString = filePath;
    s1.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = s1;
    foreach (List<EventElement> item in insertList)
---------------------SNIP----------------------------
//Adding-data-to-database logic
```

I mean to write the loaded data into a database deployed localy, but the the problem is that it does not accept my hamhanded methods of simply adding the database's filepath as the `filepath` string.

So, to summarize:
How do I correctly connect to a database situated on my C:/?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in your web.config you will find <connectionStrings>...You can declaire the connection string in there

Comment: "How do I correctly connect to a database" : see [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Btw. `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`, so you should probably get into the habit of [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx) it correctly.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic 
I'm using SQL2008.

Comment: @Corak
The connection is disposed upon the completion of my data entry loop. Are you suggesting I should put it before the loop?

Comment: I don't see any `try ... finally` in your code example, so if something goes wrong while inserting the data, an exception will be thrown and the disposing of the connection won't happen. If you get into the habit of using `using` with everything that implements `IDisposable`, you wont have to worry about proper disposal of resources ever again. ^_^

Comment: @Corak
That advice sure goes to the "keep in mind"-board!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You do not simply pass a file path. The connection string needs to follow a certain convention. For example

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;
Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for more

Comment: So my problem simply was that I tried to handle the server as a simple file instead of actually going through the appropriate steps to connect to it?

Comment: Yes. More parameters are needed. A database is not just a document. It being a local file is just one special case. Thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: Do you have any further advice for when I will be making the connection dynamic?
Thanks for taking the time to educate me.

Comment: Keep the connection string in a config file, like `Dev N00B` said. This will enable you to change it if necessary without rebuilding the application. It's hard to suggest much more without knowing the specifics of your situation